Query string operator in elastic doesn't work with multiple fields and dashes
I have the following elastic example query that checks on product title:
GET new_customer_order_items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
           "query_string": {
                "fields": ["product.title"],
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "query": "*Test product - Brand*"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

This works well. However, I want the user to be able to search on many fields. I want the user to also be able to search on the EAN field for example:
GET new_customer_order_items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
           "query_string": {
                "fields": ["product.title", "product.ean"],
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "query": "*Test product - Brand*"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

However, when I add another field. The query doesn't retrieve any documents anymore. If I remove the "-" dashes, the following queries both work:
GET new_customer_order_items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
           "query_string": {
                "fields": ["product.title", "product.ean"],
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "query": "*Test product - Brand*"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET new_customer_order_items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
           "query_string": {
                "fields": ["product.title"],
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "query": "*Test product*"
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Can I solve this so that the user can still search with the dashes?

Is title mapped as text and ean mapped as keyword or do they have different analyzers associated with them? Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

They use the same analyzers, the default. They also are text fields and elastic version is 8.4. I solved it for now by adding \ in front of special characters. This seems to work.
